# ASP.NET MVC and NHibernate coupling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have just started learning NHibernate.

Over the past few months I have been using IoC / DI (structuremap) and the repository pattern and it has made my applications much more loosely coupled and easier to test.

When switching my persistence layer to NHibernate I decided to stick with my repositories. Currently I am creating a new session on each method call but of course this means that I can not benefit from lazy loading.

Therefore I wish to implement session-per-request but in doing so this will make my web project dependent on NHibernate (perhaps this is not such a bad thing?). I was planning to inject ISession into my repositories and create and dispose sessions on beginrequest/endrequest events (see http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/05/do-you-need-a-framework.aspx)

Is this a good approach? Presumably I cannot use session-per-request without having a reference to NHibernate in my web project?

Having the web project dependent on NHibernate prompts my next (few) questions - why even bother with the repository? Since my web app is calling services that talk to the repositories, why not ditch the repositories and just add my NHibernate persistance code inside the services? And finally, is there really any need to split out into so many projects. Is a web project and an infrastructure project sufficient?

I realise that I have veered off a bit from my original question but it seems that everyone seems to have their own opinion on these topics. Some people use the repository pattern with NHibernate, some don't. Some people stick their mapping files with the related classes, others have a separate project for this.

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: I just started using MVC...and honestly, I see no use for lazy loading in the view. I just make sure the appropriate fields are eagerly loaded. IMO things are much simpler if the scope of the session stays inside the action method.

Comment: It may not be useful in the view but is certainly useful in the services used to build the view model, and it saves some complexity in the repository layer. An example would be an Order that has many Order Lines. On a page displaying a list or Orders I wouldn't want to eagerly load every OrderLine. However, when I drilled in to the order I would want the OrderLines. Using lazy loading allows me to have one simple Order repository and means I dont have to have additional repository methods for just loading orderlines.

Comment: Just a note on session scope - what about a page containing multiple partial views rendered by different actions (e.g. using RenderAction). Surely it would be better for these to save the same session (per page request) than have a session per action?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you...Lazy loading is very nice and I use it all the time (just not in view code). I haven't had to use RenderAction yet, so maybe I will eventually need to reuse the session across actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't make the business logic dependent on NHibernate. I wrote a (more or less simple) class to create the session into a context:

```
using (TransactionService.CreateTransaction())
{
  // use repository here

  // rollback on exception, only commit when reach this last line:
  TransactionService.Commit();
}
```

You just get an IDisposable, you don't need to know the session.

The repositories gets an API to access the session. For instance:

```
// example repository implementation
public Entity Get(Guid id)
{
  return SessionProvider.Session.Get<Entity>(id);
}
```

To implement this, I put the session into a `ThreadStatic` variable, which is initialized in `CreateTransaction` and returned by `SessionProvider.Session`.

Comment: @Stefan, can you explain how this works with session per request. How/where are you creating and disposing of the session?

Comment: I create the session in `TransactionService.CreateTransaction`. there I return a tiny class which implements `IDisposable` and calls the `TransactionService` in Dispose (I actually send an event which is registered by the `TransactionService` when it creates this object.) There the session is closed. When your request comes in, you open the transaction by using `TransactionService.CreateTransaction`. Then it is there.

Comment: care to share the code for your TransactionService? No offence, but the above code doesn't really help me as it stands.

Comment: It consists of some classes and is coupled with our infrastructure. So even if I could, it wouldn't help you much. The key is the ThreadStatic variable which represents the context. The rest is actually just an API built around it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net). It answers everything you need, including, how to separate data layer (NHibernate), web layer, and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the TransactionScope class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx